# Saddleback search starting point

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell

I'm currently reading ***Algorithm Design with Haskell by Richard Bird & Jeremy Gibbons***, the ***Saddleback search*** algorithm is given in chapter 4 after binary search, The problem given for motivation is :

given `f:N x N -> N` is strictly increasing in both arguments, and a value `t` find all the pairs `(x,y)` such that `f(x,y)=t`.

The first definition is given by `search f t =[(x,y) | x ← [0..t],y ← [0..t],t == f(x,y)]`,which searches starting from the origin at the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner, (the indices are increasing from bottom to top and from left to right), then the book proceeds for improvements.

The second definition is given by `search f t =[(x,y) | x ← [0..t], y ← [t,t −1..0],t == f(x, y)]`,
The book quotes this definition with

"The first improvement is to start at the top-left rather than the bottom-left corner", then the book continues till it becomes `Theta(m+n)` for a matrix with dimensions `n x m`.

The final algorithm looks like this

```
search f t = searchIn (0,t)
 where searchIn (x, y) | x>t ∨ y<0 =[]
 | z<t = searchIn (x+1, y)
 | z == t = (x, y):searchIn (x+1, y−1)
 | z>t = searchIn (x,y−1)
  where z = f(x,y)
```

Why is it the case? What's wrong with starting from the origin (0,0)?, also
why take x-coordinate to be *increasing* and y-coordinate to be *decreasing*, or vice versa (I've seen it on leetCode with x decreasing and y increasing), why not take both coordinates in increasing direction?

Comment: The difference between the two is the search pattern. I can guess what the search patterns are, but you should [edit] the question to explicitly state what the search patterns are.

Comment: I've included the final algorithm which encodes the search patterns, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical input to the problem will look like this:

[image: Typical input pattern. A curvy line begins in the top left and ends in the bottom right, separating a pure white patch from a pure black patch. Some grey spots appear along the curve.]

The black pixels represent values that are larger than `t`, the white smaller, and the grey equal. Our goal is to find all the grey spots. Ideally, to do this search, we'd just like to walk along the boundary between black and white. The only problem is we don't know where that boundary starts, so we need to search even to know where to search. If we start at the bottom left, we would have to do something like this:

[image: The previous curve is shown again, with a new red curve added. The red curve begins with a straight line from the bottom left corner, extending vertically to the previous curve's start in the top left, then following the previous curve towards the bottom right.]

The first step is to find the boundary, which we can do by scanning up from the bottom left until we find it. But then... we must turn around! The remainder of the search, we proceed down and to the right. So we must separate our search into two phases, one to find the boundary, and another to follow it. If you start in the top left, though...

[image: The first curve appears a third time, again with a red curve added. This time, the red curve begins in the top left corner, extending vertically downward in a straight line until it reaches the previous curve, then mimicking the previous curve as it meanders toward the bottom right.]

This time, we don't have to turn around, and this means we can reuse the same code that we use for following the rest of the boundary to find the boundary in the first place!

This answers "why not start at the origin". The other question, "why not increase in one direction and decrease in the other", well... you can. It's an almost identical problem, and an almost identical algorithm will solve it.

Comment: Thanks, my other question was why not increase both directions, but I think this answers it well.

Comment: @KareemTaha I don't understand what "why not increase both directions" means. Isn't `f` already increasing in both directions?

Comment: I meant the direction of iterating over indices.

Comment: @KareemTaha Increasing the indices in both directions would be moving up and to the right. The boundary moves up and to the left. So if you only move up-right, you will only ever cross the boundary once.

Answer (score 2):

I've been reading [this](http://typeocaml.com/2015/03/31/pearl-no-3-saddleback-search/) and I think I now understand why, in the link, there is a simpler problem about *Target sum of two sorted lists*,the problem statement :

Given a value k and two sorted lists of integers (all being distinct), find all pairs of integers (i, j) where i + j == k.

The solution has to decide *which* list to move on `list1` or `list2` or both, and *when*, it then sorts `list1` in ascending order and `list2` in descending order, this helps in assigning a decision for each case

let `i` denote elements `list1`and `j` denote elements in `list2`,

```
i+j < k
i+j > k
i+j == k
```

maps to `move on` (`list1, list2, both`) respectively.

---

Now the same applies in the matrix case, assume we start from the origin (0,0),
since we traverse each column bottom up, let us be in column `a`, assume we hit an element `z` at row `b` such that `z=f(a,b) >= t` then we can leave column `a` and row `b`, actually the whole upper rectangle having `(a,b)` as bottom-left corner (since `f` is strictly increasing in both arguments, and both, starting from the origin, are increasing).

The next starting point will be `(a+1,0)`,  but when `z=f(a,b) < t` we can do nothing, just complete in the current column until we hit an element that is greater than `t`, or then column ends.

From the search algorithm implementation in the question, it seems that choosing one index to be increasing and the other to be decreasing, introduces more regularity in the implementation, also the new starting points are usually inside the matrix, so we are not doing linear search for points that would reduce the search space, unlike starting from `(a+1,0)`.

I'm not able to do full analysis to see how time complexity is affected in worst case, but I think this is convincing.

Any comments are welcomed, full analysis solutions are greatly appreciated.